# SQL query to fetch data into transpose form

Tags: sql, ms-access, unpivot

I want to fetch data from MS Access to Excel using a SQL query. But I want data to transpose and fetch. As an example:

Database looks like:

```
Name age education city
David 24 MS New York
```

I want the query to result in below form:

```
Name David
age 24
education MS
city New Yor
```

If I write `SELECT * from table;` it will fetch data in the same order as in database. But I want them to transpose.

Comment: mysql or sql-server... or ms-access? Please tag only the one database that you are running.

Comment: This type of thing is better done in the presentation layer, in my opinion. Otherwise you're mixing data types in a single column, and that never ends well.

Comment: Yep, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

A simple, portable solution is to use `union all` - however additional casting might be needed to align the datatypes (I would assume that `age` is of a numeric datatype):

In MS Access:

```
select 'name' col, name val from mytable
union all select 'age', CStr(age) from mytable
union all select 'education', education from mytable
union all select 'city', city from mytable
```

In MySQL:

```
select 'name' col, name val from mytable
union all select 'age', cast(age as char(3)) from mytable
union all select 'education', education from mytable
union all select 'city', city from mytable
```

In SQL Server, this is simpler and more efficiently done with `cross apply`:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    ('name', name), 
    ('age', cast(age as varchar(3)),
    ('education', education),
    ('city', city)
) x(col, val)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col
    ,colval
FROM (
    SELECT name
        ,age
        ,education
        ,city
    FROM MyTable
    ) p
UNPIVOT(ColVal FOR Col IN (
            name
            ,age
            ,education
            ,city
            )) AS unpvt
```